# how to re-write for loop to list comprehension

Tags: python

I wonder if there is a way to re write following code to list comprehension. Thank you

inputDict is a dict

```
result = {}
for key in inputDict:
    total = 0
    for nodes in inputDict :
        total = total + (key in inputDict[nodes])
    result.update({key : total})
```

Comment: It don't looks to me that your code work itself, could you update you code?

Comment: A _list comprehension_? You are creating a dictionary here, not a list.

Comment: What part of your code does not work?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid could it return a list of pairs, then convert to dictionary,like result = dict([(x,y) ...]) ?

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis the code works. I am learning to write list comprehension.

Comment: Are `inputDict` and `digraph` supposed to be the same dict?

Comment: Also, `result.update(key , total)` is definitely not going to work.

Comment: @user2357112 agree. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly than you can try:

```
result = dict((key, sum(key in inputDict[nodes] for nodes in digraph)) for key in inputDict)
```

Or if you need a list:

```
result = [(key, sum(key in inputDict[nodes] for nodes in digraph)) for key in inputDict]
```

Or:

```
result = [(key, sum(key in vals for nodes in digraph)) for key, vals in inputDict]
```

Comment: nice work.It is hard to thinking like this way. Do you have any suggestions for how to learn python list comprehension? Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @galaxyan, is the matter of time only, i think. It is no so difficult as you can think, list comprh is just a way to write 'for loop' shortly, and to be honestly not the only a way.

Comment: It's not always the best way either. Remember code clarity is a very important. Code is written once but read hundreds of times. If your comprehension begins to get tough to look at there is nothing wrong with making it into a traditional `for` block

Answer (score 1):

Not a list comprehension, since you're not building a list. However, the operation you're trying to perform, which appears to be counting how many nodes link to each node, can easily be done by using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to count how many times each node appears in the values of `inputDict`:

```
import collections
import itertools
result = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(inputDict.values()))
```

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) takes `inputDict.values()` and strings all the lists of nodes in there into one big iterator. (Or maybe those are sets of nodes. It's hard to tell.) [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) then counts how many times it sees each element. The result is a `collections.Counter` instance, which behaves mostly like a dict. There are a few differences, though, so if you need a result that's exactly of `dict` type, you can call `dict` on it:

```
result = dict(result)
```

Note that `Counter` returns a count of 0 for items not in the Counter, but `dict` doesn't do that. If you call `dict` on it, you may need to fill in a count of 0 for nodes that never appeared in `inputDict.values()`.

---

The use of `Counter` and `chain` can hide some of what's going on here, so here's how you'd write that without importing library code:

```
result = {}

# Initialize counts to 0, to make sure nodes that don't appear in the values have the
# right count and to make sure we don't need to check `if node in result` later.
for node in inputDict:
    result[node] = 0

# Go through and count node occurrences.
for adjacent_nodes in inputDict.values():
    for node in adjacent_nodes:
        result[node] += 1
```

There isn't an easy way to turn this into a comprehension without algorithmic complexity sacrifices, which is part of why `collections.Counter` exists.